# $z\mapsto \frac1{z^2-1/2}$ uniformly approximable by polynomials over the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be the holomorphic function defined by $z\mapsto \frac1{z^2-1/2}.$ It's asking wether or not $f$ can be uniformly approximable by polynomials over the unit circle $S^1.$

I feel bad, because to apply Runge Theorem I need the fact that $\Bbb{C}\setminus{S^1}$ is connected but it's not.

Perhaps it's a typo and I need to deal with $\overline{D(0,1)}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: compare $\oint_\Gamma z f(z)\; dz$ to what you would get with a polynomial, where $\Gamma$ is the positively oriented unit circle.

Comment: For your first integralif I use Cauchy integral formula I get 1/2 and we get  $0$ with a polynomial. Ok the if $P_n$ converges uniformly to $zf(z)$ then the integral converge as well. But here it's $zf(z)$ I suppose I can relate it to $f(z)?$

Comment: If $P_n(z) \to f(z)$ then $z P_n(z) \to z f(z)$.  If $P_n(z)$ is a polynomial, then so is $z P_n(z)$.

Comment: arf!! I should have seen this. Thanks